# Call function inside @NgModule decorator

Tags: angular

I'm looking around how to call the function inside @NgModule decorator.

For my purpose, I would like to be able to call isDevMode() function which is built-in into the angular core.

So in @NgModule, I'm trying to do conditional check am I in dev or prod mode and based on that import or not specific module.

Workarround can be to simply add production flag into envioronment files, but in my case it shouldn't work.

Reason for that is because for some envioronment I would like to be able to dynamically set production flag to true of false. So, isDevMode() function do that already based on --prod flag that is passed during ng build or ng serve, but problem is that I can't do the following:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ....
    isDevMode() : TestModule : []
    ....
]});
```

I'm getting an error if I want to get AOT compliant application.

The reason is obvious because NgModule requires static content and functions calls are forbidden, but I'm wondering is there any workaround for this.

Error:

```
ERROR in app/app.module.ts(169,5): Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'isDevMode'
```

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you can create a module with static `forRoot` method which returns the module definition.

Like this:

```
@NgModule({
})
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    var data = {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      imports: [],
      exports: []
    };
    if(condition) {
      data.imports.push(YourModuleToExport);
      data.exports.push(YourModuleToExport);
    }
    return data;
  }
}
```

I am not 100% sure since I never used it this way, but I should work just fine.

The last thing is you maybe will have to use `import(path).then(mod => mod.YourModuleToExport)` instead of `YourModuleToExport`. So the module will get `lazy-loaded`.

Then you should be able to use the forRoot method in the module imports like when you use RouterModule.

```
imports: [
   SharedModule.ForRoot()
]
```

Source: https://medium.com/slackernoon/when-to-use-angulars-forroot-method-400094a0ebb7

Comment: but what if I am using existing module and not building my own so I am not able to do it like you proposed? Can I overwrite forRoot of existing module which is not in my control?

Comment: I don't see the problem. You will just add the existing module to the import and export so the Shared module will export the modules that you want to conditionally import to the app module. And you can inherit the module and overwrite the method. You are not conditionally importing the Shared module, that will be always here. You are conditionally importing the `YourModuleToExport` and it can be any module you want.

Comment: I will create a stackliz for you :) so you can see.

Comment: Now it is clear. I didn't understand on first because I was on mobile phone. Stackliz is not required but maybe because of others it is good if you can. Once I tried it I'll accept your answer :). Thanks

Comment: it doesn't work... here are two gists files: https://gist.github.com/a4ff732691a79d4ae9f122135dde5900
https://gist.github.com/harishajdarevic/92a1375aa2ae3ddf341477d6bb7653bf

ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'StoreConditionalImportModule' was called.

Comment: Wierd it compiles in my case, but it seems it doesn't import the module. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dhadys

Comment: It seems the problem is the `instrument` function can I see the function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199382/discussion-between-pavel-b-and-haris-hajdarevic).